# Robot/spam picture filter for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a plugin or gem that has the picture of letters or words to filter spam and robots.

Has anyone seen one of these for rails?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There [isn't really a shortage of them.](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=captcha+rails)